# how to write tag Name and ID for ASP.NET Server Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

I am developing an asp.net server control
and in the

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
```

method
I just write something equivalent to this:

```
output.Write("<input id='"+ClientID+"' value="+value ... etc.);
```

so for the ID it's just ClientID i guess but for the name I'm not really sure,
I see that asp.net controls have a bit of difference between them (_ for id is $ for name),

**Is there some API from asp.net for getting the Name** or we just have to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this property (`Control.UniqueID`):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx